# How are French nuclear facilities and technology kept secret under the European Union?

Tags: european-union, nuclear-weapons, france, european-parliament

France is the only nuclear power in the EU. How does it protect its facilities and maintain the secrecy of technology when the European Parliament has at least some say in French security and military matters. The fear here is of nuclear technology being leaked to non-nuclear states. Do they have any special protections or mandated agreements for this under the EU framework?

Comment: What do you mean by *'the European Parliament has at least some say in French security and military matters'*? Can you be more specific about what sort of influence you refer to?

Comment: Theres a reason there isnt an integrated EU armed forces, and EU members maintain their own foreign policy…

Comment: Can you clarify "nuclear facilities and technology"?  France may be the only EU country with nuclear weapons, but it is not the only EU country with nuclear facilities.  According to Wikipedia there are twelve other countries with nuclear reactors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_power_in_the_European_Union

Comment: Who has this "fear"?

Comment: Also Germany hosts US nuclear weapons that its own planes can deliver with US approval https://www.dw.com/en/us-set-to-upgrade-controversial-nukes-stationed-in-germany/a-52855886 (And so do Belgium, the Netherlands and Italy.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The military cooperation in the EU is on the level of relatively vague security guarantees and overall [policy coordination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Security_and_Defence_Policy). It does not extend to the command and control of military units. [EU Battlegroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EU_Battlegroup) remain *national* forces which have been put on alert for possible EU deployments.

There is a lot of bilateral and multilateral cooperation among EU members. often under the NATO umbrella, but that again involves *national* forces putting individual units under multinational headquarters. France no longer has any nuclear army units, just air force and navy.

I also think that you're under-estimating just how much major industrial nations already know about nuclear weapons technology. The [Non-Proliferation Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Non-Proliferation_of_Nuclear_Weapons) allows full *civilian* nuclear development against the monitoring of nuclear materials and the promise not to use it for *military* purposes.

Comment: EU BGs are more like a political fantasy as they never deployed in a combat zone. Also, France is not even in NATOs Nuclear Planning Group. https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natolive/topics_50069.htm They really like to keep their nukes to themselves.